# Order By Case Especifico

Tags: sql-server

Contexto: Necesito realizar un orden especifico
en el cual necesito ordenar por el "Estado del libro" en este caso un Order By
que se pueda ordenar por:
-Todos(Todos los estados, disponible y no disponible)
-Disponible
-No disponible

El nombre de la tabla se llama DISPON

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que tengo:

```
        CASE WHEN @Orden2 = 0 THEN DISPON END,
        CASE WHEN @Orden2 = 1 THEN DISPON = 1 END,
        CASE WHEN @Orden2 = 2 THEN DISPON = 2 END
```

Mi problema es como especificar para que ordene por Disponible y no Disponible.

Para mayor información es un procedimiento almacenado que pienso ejecutar para que le de funcionalidad a los Radiobuttons que estoy implementando para ordenar.

Comment: qué significa "ordenar por todos los estados", "ordenar por disponibles" y "ordenar por no disponibles"?. Puedes poner un ejemplo de los resultados que quieres?

Comment: Te comento Lamak tengo un Gridview Libros, el cual contiene el codigo del libro, el nombre del libro, el autor, la editorial, su estado y el ultimo lector.
Lo que busco hacer es que cuando seleccionen un Radiobutton de los estados del libro se actualice el gridview acorde a lo que seleccionaron, que en este caso puede ser Todos los estados que contiene(libros disponibles y no disponibles),o solo muestre los libros disponible o solo los libros no disponible.Espero hayas comprendido

Comment: pero eso entonces no es "ordenar", es "filtrar", no?

Comment: Si puede ser filtrar si es asi como lo comprendes

Comment: mmm, es que simplemente no veo cómo podría ser "ordenar" lo que quieres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente lo que necesitas es una condición `WHERE` que filtre los datos dependiendo de una variable:

```
SELECT
    Columnas
FROM dbo.DISPON
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN @Orden2 = 0 THEN 1
        WHEN @Orden2 = 1 AND Estado = 'DISPONIBLE' THEN 1
        WHEN @Orden2 = 2 AND Estado = 'NO DISPONIBLE' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END = 1
;
```